# How to read the email from the different account in the outlook

Tags: python, outlook

In my outlook, I have 2 accounts(account 1 and account 2). Account 1 is the default account.

**I am trying to read the email from the account 2 from the python code**. I tried different approach, but it did not work.

Am posting a my code where it reads from my default account. Could you please help me to read the emails from the account 2(which is not default)

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import time
import datetime
import re
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
all_inbox = inbox.Items
val_date = datetime.date.today()
 
sub_today = 'test4'
att_today = '20201018_2.xlsx'    
#att_today = re.match(regex_, )
for msg in all_inbox:
    if msg.Subject.find(sub_today) != -1 and msg.SentOn.date() == val_date:
        break

for att in msg.Attachments:
    if att.FileName == att_today:
        print(att_today)
        break

try:
    print(att.FileName)
    #att.SaveAsFile("C:/Users/Shwettha/Downloads/attachment/"+ att.FileName)
    att.SaveAsFile(os.path.join("D:\Script\Monitoring",att.FileName))
    print("SUCCESSFUL","Attachments Downloaded")
except:
    print("ERROR","Attachment Download Failed")
```

Answer (score 0):

*Try setting your inbox like the following*

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.Folders["0m3r@Email.com"].Folders["Inbox"]
```

---

*Or use [GetSharedDefaultFolder method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder)*

```
import win32com.client

Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
olNs = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Recip = olNs.CreateRecipient("0m3r@Email.com")
Recip.Resolve()
shared_inbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recip, "6")

for Item in shared_inbox.Items:
    print(Item.Subject)
```

Comment: Eventhough i gave above lines...it s taking the default email box

Comment: @Kanagambala look at the second example.

Comment: remember the email is case sensitive